# What is the best way to store key => value pairs, which may be deleted occasionally?

Tags: java, json, dictionary

I have a list of <key, value> which usually I stored them in JSON file. When the server starts, it should load the map from JSON file and when errors occur or there are some changes, they need to write that map to the file. I think JSON file is ok for this situation.

Now, the requirements change. When the data was processed, it should be removed from the map or the file. There might be a case when we need to remove hundreds of items. I believe we can still use JSON to store data but worried that it is not a good choice to remove a large number.

There are several thousand items and sometimes we need to remove some hundreds items although we removed normally only a few items. For the performance, read should be fast but the performance of write/remove is not our priority. If it can support transaction, it should be nice but not mandatory.

What is your advice? What is the best way to store this data in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: How many need to be stored? How fast should reads/inserts/removes be? What atomicity and durability guarantees do you need? Does this need to be transactional? [Edit] your post to reflect these further details.

Comment: Not enough information here. How much resilience do you need? What happens if an item is processed and you crash before you can write out a new file with it removed? How much performance do you need? TBH I’d just directly jump to a file based database that supports things like transactions and provides some level durability. Skip the “attempting to write your own hobbled file based database” journey and find something better to do with your time…

Comment: The external form of the data is probably of less import than the number of I/O operations performed.  In any event, it is usually best to *test first* whether the performance is adequate, and if not, to *profile* the code to determine where the performance problem lies.

Comment: You could consider a `java.util.Properties` file if the data is suitable.